# Chained dropdown boxes in jQuery, all are firing when one is changed

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am binding an ajax post to these boxes with "live", onchange event. But apparently "onchange" fires when a box is generated also. So which even should I use to only fire the box that is clicked on or acted on with the keyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#yourselect').change(function(){
   // what you want inside...
});
```